# SAS Overwrite numeric variable to character

Tags: sas, character, numeric

I have a numeric variable (e.g. cylinders) and I want to overwrite it to a character (and keep it in the same order in the table).

I would like to do it in one step. Is there any smart way to do it?

```
data cars; set sashelp.cars; 
if cylinders >= 6 then cylinders = 'Big'; 
if cylinders < 6 then cylinders 'Ecocar'; 
run;
```

I am just trying to avoid the tedious steps of creating a new character variable and then having to reposition that new character variable to where cylinders was in the table.

Comment: How much do you know about the dataset?  For example do you know the names of the first and last variables?

Comment: Last variable name may be changing... I think that it deviates from the purpose. Last variable name has nothing to do with the variable I want to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using Proc format

> 

```
Proc format;
      Value CylSize
           0 - 6 = ‘Ecocar’
           7 - high = ‘Big’;
Run;

Data cars;
   Set sashelp.cars;
    Format Cylinders CylSize.;
Run;
```

Comment: I really like that this solution is succinct and it does not depend on other factors; problem is on column `Cylinders` and we only deal with that column without creating dependencies in our code with respect to other columns. Good SAS programming @Helly !

Comment: This will work perfectly if you need to change the way it is displayed or how it enters other SAS applications (some SAS apps rely on the format to change how the variable behaves, such as Visual Analytics). It does not convert it into a character column, though. If that does not matter then a format is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Once a variable is defined, you cannot change it from one type to another without creating a new variable. You will need to define where it needs to be in the table before making it. The quick way would be using a `retain` statement before your `set` statement to define the order of pre-existing variables without worrying what type they are.

```
data cars; 
    retain make model type origin drivetrain _cylinders;
    length cylinders $15.;

    set sashelp.cars(rename=(cylinders = _cylinders)); 

    if _cylinders >= 6 then cylinders = 'Big'; 
    if _cylinders < 6 then cylinders = 'Ecocar'; 

    drop _cylinders;
run;
```

Another way is by first creating a dummy table that looks exactly the way you want it and has all of the variable attributes that you need. Populate it only with one single empty row so it's easy to rearrange later. Let's call it `cars_attribs`. For example:

```
Type    C    C     C    C      C          C         N    N       N          ...
Column  make model type origin drivetrain cylinders msrp invoice enginesize ...
Row                                                 .    .       .          ...
```

Use this table in a `set` statement with `obs=0` to always hold your favorite variable positions.

```
   data cars; 
    set cars_attribs(obs=0)
        sashelp.cars(rename=(cylinders = _cylinders));
    ;

    if _cylinders >= 6 then cylinders = 'Big'; 
    if _cylinders < 6 then cylinders = 'Ecocar'; 

    drop _cylinders;
run;
```

If you ever want to change variable positions, simply re-arrange `cars_attribs` in Enterprise Guide by dragging columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can query metadata to find the order of the variables and use that to define the new variable at the right place.

But let's assume that if the order of the variables is that important to you then you already know what the name of the first variable is.

Include just the variables up to CYLINDERS by using a position based variable list.  Then define your new variable.  Then re-read the observation again with ALL of the variables so that the variables after CYLINDERS appear after the new variable.

Now you add code to populate the new variable. Drop the old one. And rename the new one to have the old name.

So if the first variable is named MAKE your code looks like:

```
data want ;
  set sashelp.cars(keep=MAKE -- CYLINDERS);
  length new_var $10 ;
  set sashelp.cars;

  if cylinders >= 6 then new_var = 'Big'; 
  else if not missing(cylinders) then new_var = 'Ecocar'; 

  drop CYLINDERS;
  rename new_var=CYLINDERS;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use rename and retain:

```
data cars(drop=temp);
retain Make Model Type Origin DriveTrain MSRP Invoice EngineSize cylinders Horsepower 
       MPG_City MPG_Highway Weight Wheelbase Length;
set sashelp.cars(rename=(cylinders=temp));
if temp >= 6 then cylinders = 'Big'; 
if temp < 6 then cylinders = 'Ecocar'; 
run;
```

You can also use proc sql:

```
proc sql;
create table cars as 
select Make, Model, Type, Origin, DriveTrain, MSRP, Invoice, EngineSize,
        case when cylinders >= 6 then 'Big'
             when cylinders < 6 then 'Ecocar' end as cylinders,
        Horsepower, MPG_City, MPG_Highway, Weight, Wheelbase, Length
from sashelp.cars
;
quit;
```